# Issues on Android memory management system

Tags: android, memory, android-service

The goal of my App is it must run forever without user's interaction. But it has failed many times probably memory related issues. According to the Android document, Android first let user warn by onTrimMemory() if system needs memory. Nevertheless if Android system needs more memory then throw OOM(Out of memory) exception and app will crash. My app uses Service with Activity and Service runs with sticky notification.(That will keep Service being foreground and that is not high level target to be killed) Below code creates sticky notification.

```
private void startForegroundService(Context context, String text){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                text,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    } else {
        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    }

    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.background_control))
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    startForeground(MAIN_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

First what I don't understand part is memory related events are not in order. For example, if Android needs memory, then first should throw onTrimMemory() level in order (5, 20, 60, ..) and if needs more then throw OOM. But so far I experienced is not sequential, it totally random. And my App doesn't occur memory leak. I checked that with Android IDE Profiler many times. And some testing apps doesn't occur memory issues. Which mean probably no memory leak I think.

Second I want to know how to estimate memory exactly. I'm now using Runtime.getRuntime() to check current memory. Not only heap memory of App but also system. I log when crash happens, but memory is pretty much enough. Below code is for logging when events happen.

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long totalMem = runtime.totalMemory();
    long freeMem = runtime.freeMemory();
    final double usedMemInMB = (double) (totalMem - freeMem) / 1048576;

    LogManager.addLog(LogManager.WARNING_TAG,
            "onTrimMemory Level(" + level + "), Free/ Used/ Total/ Avail: "
                    + String.format("%5.2f", (freeMem / 1024.0 / 1024.0)) + "/ "
                    + String.format("%5.2f", usedMemInMB) + "/ "
                    + String.format("%5.2f", (totalMem / 1024.0 / 1024.0)) + "/ "
                    + String.format("%7.2f", (getAvailableMemory() / 1024.0 / 1024.0)) + "MB"
    );
}

private long getAvailableMemory() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

    return memoryInfo.availMem;
}
```

So I don't understand why Android throw onTrimMemory() or OOM or even kill my App without warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one memory leak on my app has been solved.
I recommend to use the Profiler of Android Studio and tack to find where is leaking if somebody is suffering on this problem.